# Pens in metapost in ConTeXt stop working after clipping is used

Tags: context, metapost, bugs

There's a weird bug in ConTeXt ver. 2020.03.10: after a clipping mask is used, pens stop changing their thicknesses.

```
\starttext
\startMPcode
picture p;
p := image(draw (0, 0)--(1cm, 1cm) withpen pencircle scaled 1cm;);
clip p to (unitsquare shifted (-1/2, -1/2) scaled 10 cm); % <- this one
draw p;
draw (0, 0)--(-1cm, 1cm) withpen pencircle scaled 1cm;
\stopMPcode
\stoptext
```

produces a picture with one thick line and one thin line:

[image]

while

```
\starttext
\startMPcode
picture p;
p := image(draw (0, 0)--(1cm, 1cm) withpen pencircle scaled 1cm;);
draw p;
draw (0, 0)--(-1cm, 1cm) withpen pencircle scaled 1cm;
\stopMPcode
\stoptext
```

produces two thick lines as intended:

[image]

I [reported](http://tracker.luatex.org/view.php?id=1021) it earlier this year (although, apparently, in a wrong place, since I assumed it might be a LuaTeX/mplib bug) and, as I understood, it was fixed in future ConTeXt versions. But meanwhile, is there's a way to patch the current version so that the thing works?

Comment: It works as expected in newest releases. Either you'll have to wait until TL21 (I guess you're using a TeX Live distribution) or compile using the standalone distribution from [here](http://www.pragma-ade.nl/install.htm)

Comment: Sure I can try and install the newest version manually, but that would require anyone who builds my project to do so and what's "the" newest version would change over time. If, on the other hand, I can point to a patch for the current TL version of ConTeXt, or, even better, add some kind of workaround for my project for this thing to work, it would be way more reproducible.

Comment: For reproducability (e.g. in CI) you can use Docker images of recent ConTeXt versions: https://hub.docker.com/r/contextgarden/context

Comment: Yes, thank you. Something like this is probably what I'll do eventually. But other things being equal I'd rather know how to fix the bug and have it fixed for the current version if possible.

Comment: If you ask for this peculiar fix on ConteXt mailing list (ntg-context@ntg.nl) you may get it quite quickly.